# Caught different behaviour of ArrayList.get() method in IF condition

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList contains,**arr = [151,151,167,224,224......]**, it's a very long ArrayList; when I do the below code :

**if(arr.get(0)!= arr.get(1))
return arr.get(0);**

Here the output **I am getting is 151, But it is wrong** It should not go under the if condition.
Please Let me know Why it is going. Is there anything we should be aware of ArrayList.get() method?

Then changed the condition to  :

**if((int)arr.get(0)!= (int)arr.get(1)) return arr.get(0);**

then the condition become false, and then its not going under if condition.

Comment: It's autoboxing: the capital versions are boxed primitives / objects, and are separate objects in memory. Integers are only really commonly cached in the byte range `[-128, 127]`. The `==` operator for objects will compare for reference equality (i.e. are they the same object), _not_ for the same value. For that, there is `Object#equals`.

Comment: Show the declaration of your `ArrayList`.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)